# How to use a conditional or in linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq

In the following `GetByExpression`, sometimes the `r.branchid` is `null`. How do I add a conditional in there so it utilises a different field (`r.Invoice.Branch.Id`) to check against when `r.branchid` is `null`?

```
var t = receiptRepo
 .GetByExpression(r => r.BranchId == branchId)
 .Where(r => r.Date == selectedDate && r.BatchId == null)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: `r => (r.BranchId ?? r.Invoice.BranchId) == branchId` Here if we have `r.BranchId` being `null` we use `r.Invoice.BranchId`

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary operation

```
(r.BranchId != null? r.BranchId:r.Invoice.Branch.Id ) == branchId //or whatever you want to compare
```

Comment: Thanks, gotta finish testing but works so far

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator `??`:

```
r => (r.BranchId ?? r.Invoice.BranchId) == branchId
```

Here if `r.BranchId` is `null` we use `r.Invoice.BranchId` to compare with `branchId`. Note, that we can *chain* `??` operators, e.g.

```
r => (r.BranchId ?? r.Invoice.BranchId ?? r.Bill.BranchId) == branchId
```

we try `BranchId` if it's `null`, we have a look at `r.Invoice.BranchId` and if it's `null` we get `r.Bill.BranchId` etc.

Your Linq query can be

```
var t = receiptRepo
  .GetByExpression(r => (r.BranchId ?? r.Invoice.BranchId) == branchId)
  .Where(r => r.Date == selectedDate && r.BatchId == null)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Tried it, but failed as it does not allow the ?? function with "int?"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var t = receiptRepo
        .GetByExpression(r => (r?.BranchId ?? r.Invoice.BranchId) == branchId)
        .Where(r => r.Date == selectedDate && r.BatchId == null)
        .ToList();
```